# Combine Table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables would like to combine.

I would like the table will automatically add a row for `image2` when there are new `generalname` in `image1`.

[image]

[image]

```
 select B.Trsdate, count(B.Billno) As Billno, sum(B.pax) As Pax, sum(B.Grossamount) As GrossAmount, sum(B.discountamount) As Discount, sum(B.taxamount) As Tax, sum(B.servicechargeamount) As SCharge, sum(B.nettamount) As NettAmt, sum(B.rounddiff) As RDiff, sum(B.roundamt) As RoundAmt, sum(B.reversalYN) As RevBillNo, SUM(GD.CASH) AS 'P_CASH', SUM(GD.VISA) AS 'P_VISA', SUM(GD.MASTER) AS 'P_MASTER', SUM(GD.AMEX) AS 'P_Amex', SUM(GD.CityLedger) AS 'P_CityLedger', SUM(GD.OtherPayment) As 'P_Other'
from vpos_eod_bills As B
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT TrsNo,SUM(CASH) as CASH,SUM(Visa) as Visa, SUM(Master) as Master, SUM(Amex) AS Amex, SUM(CityLedger) as CityLedger, SUM(OtherPayment) as OtherPayment, SUM(Total) as Total FROM 
            (
                select TrsNo, GENERALNAME,
                (case WHEN(Generalname IN ('CASH'))
                THEN
                    SUM(AMOUNT)
                ELSE
                    0
                END) as 'CASH',

                (case WHEN(Generalname IN ('VISA'))
                THEN
                    SUM(AMOUNT)
                ELSE
                    0
                END) as 'Visa',

                (case WHEN(Generalname IN ('MASTER'))
                THEN
                    SUM(AMOUNT)
                ELSE
                    0
                END) as 'Master',

                (case WHEN(Generalname IN ('AMEX'))
                THEN
                    SUM(AMOUNT)
                ELSE
                    0
                END) as 'Amex',

                (case WHEN(Generalname = 'City Ledger' OR Generalname = 'CREDIT A/C' OR Generalname = 'BOSS' OR Generalname = 'ENTERTAINMENT')
                THEN
                    SUM(AMOUNT)
                ELSE
                    0
                END) as 'CityLedger',

                (case WHEN(Generalname not IN ('CASH','Voucher','VISA','MASTER','AMEX','JCB','City Ledger','CREDIT A/C','BOSS','ENTERTAINMENT') and (Generalname not like '%card%') and (Generalname not like '%Coupon%') and (Generalname not like '%GROUPON%') and (Generalname not like '%COURSE%'))
                THEN
                    SUM(AMOUNT)
                ELSE
                    0
                END) as 'OtherPayment',

                SUM(AMOUNT) as Total

                from Vpos_eod_GeneralDetails
                where BillType = 'P'
                group by TrsNo, GeneralName
            ) As A
    Group By A.trsno
    )As GD ON GD.TrsNo = B.TrsNo
where B.PaidStatus = '1' and B.VoidStatus = '0' and (B.trsdate between '20200101' and '20200131')
group by B.trsdate
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008